# Specify a list in Json

Tags: json, c#-4.0, generics

I know this seems naive. But, I really am struck here!

I have a `List<int>` which is an input to a Service whose request format is Json.

Example:

```
List<int> lsId = new List<int>();
lsId.Add(1);
lsId.Add(2);
```

Now, how to represent this in JSON?

Any help appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON representation of that list is this

```
{
  "lsId": [
    1,
    2
  ]
}
```

Where `"lsId"` is the name of the list, and the `1` and `2` inside the `[]` is the actual   content of the list. `[]` specifies that the value for `lsId` is a list.
The `lsId` is enclosed in double quotes because in JSON, identfiers are always strings, and strings in JSON are always with double quotes, not single.

Have a look at http://www.json.org/, its explained pretty well.

Comment: Still, my Method in service gives the count as 0. What would be the issue?

Comment: @San I don't know and I can't know because you didn't include the code that does that. But that was not your question

Comment: [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        bool Methodname(List<int> lsAssignment);
This is my method

Comment: @San I dont know about that, but it seems that is an entirely different question.

Comment: Yeah.I know.Thanks anyways Tim for the info passed. Appreciated.